# spring tcp socket , authorizing clients and handle pending response

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

The Spring framework support tcp connection as well , i wrote code below to setup a simple socket server , i am confused about adding below futures to my socket server :

- authorizing clients based on a unique identifier ( for example a client secret received from client, maybe using [TCP Connection Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events) )
- send a message directly to specific client (based on identifier)
- broadcast a message

**UPDATE :**

- `Config.sendMessage` added to send message to single client
- `Config.broadCast` added to broadcast message
- `authorizeIncomingConnection` to authorize clients , accept or reject connections
- `tcpConnections` static filed added to keep tcpEvent sources

**Questions !**

- is using `tcpConnections` HashMap good idea ?!
- is the authorization method i implemented a good one ?!

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

Config.java

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class Config implements ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Config.class.getName());

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory AbstractServerConnectionFactory() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(8181);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway TcpInboundGateway(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpInboundGateway inGate = new TcpInboundGateway();
        inGate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        inGate.setRequestChannel(getMessageChannel());
        return inGate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel getMessageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @MessageEndpoint
    public class Echo {

        @Transformer(inputChannel = "getMessageChannel")
        public String convert(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
            return new String(bytes);
        }

    }

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, TcpConnection> tcpConnections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TcpConnectionEvent tcpEvent) {
        TcpConnection source = (TcpConnection) tcpEvent.getSource();
        if (tcpEvent instanceof TcpConnectionOpenEvent) {

            LOGGER.info("Socket Opened " + source.getConnectionId());
            tcpConnections.put(tcpEvent.getConnectionId(), source);

            if (!authorizeIncomingConnection(source.getSocketInfo())) {
                LOGGER.warn("Socket Rejected " + source.getConnectionId());
                source.close();
            }

        } else if (tcpEvent instanceof TcpConnectionCloseEvent) {
            LOGGER.info("Socket Closed " + source.getConnectionId());
            tcpConnections.remove(source.getConnectionId());
        }
    }

    private boolean authorizeIncomingConnection(SocketInfo socketInfo) {
        //Authorization Logic , Like Ip,Mac Address WhiteList or anyThing else !
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 2 == 0;
    }

    public static String broadCast(String message) {
        Set<String> connectionIds = tcpConnections.keySet();
        int successCounter = 0;
        int FailureCounter = 0;
        for (String connectionId : connectionIds) {
            try {
                sendMessage(connectionId, message);
                successCounter++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FailureCounter++;
            }
        }
        return "BroadCast Result , Success : " + successCounter + " Failure : " + FailureCounter;
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String connectionId, final String message) throws Exception {
        tcpConnections.get(connectionId).send(new Message<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getPayload() {
                return message;
            }

            @Override
            public MessageHeaders getHeaders() {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/notify/{connectionId}/{message}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(@PathVariable String connectionId, @PathVariable String message) {
        try {
            Config.sendMessage(connectionId, message);
            return "Client Notified !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Failed To Notify Client , cause : \n " + e.toString();
        }
    }


    @RequestMapping("/broadCast/{message}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(@PathVariable String message) {
        return Config.broadCast(message);
    }

}
```

Usage :

1. Socket Request/Response Mode
2. notify single client

   `http://localhost:8080/notify/{connectionId}/{message}`
3. broadCast

   `http://localhost:8080/broadCast/{message}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` contains a `connectionId` property. Each message coming from that client will have the same property in the `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` message header.

1. Add a custom router that keeps track of the logged-on state of each connection.
2. Lookup the connection id and if not authenticated, route to a challenge/response subflow.
3. When authenticated, route to the normal flow.

To use arbitrary messaging (rather than request/response) use a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` and `TcpSendingMessageHandler` instead of an inbound gateway. Both configured to use the same connection factory. For each message sent to the message handler, add the `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` header to target the specific client.

To broadcast, send a message for each connection id.

Comment: thank you , i updated my question , could you please take a look at it ?

Comment: Interesting technique; the hash map is fine (although you should check for `null` in `sendMessage` because there's a race condition). However, you can't do the authentication on the thread that publishes the connection opened event - that's the "accept" thread (server socket). The data will be sent on a different thread. That's why I said you need a router to route the first request on a socket through authentication logic.

Comment: can you explain more or give me a code snippet about using a router ?

Comment: Add a `@Router` to route to the authentication logic if not already authenticated. You could also use an interceptor. See the [Hello world! handshake test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/TcpSendingMessageHandlerTests.java#L900) and the [HelloWorldInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/HelloWorldInterceptor.java).

Comment: Thanks Again ! , i tried both ways , when we use router or interceptor socket server wait for client's first request to start authentication process , but what if client never send any request ? , maybe an authentication time-out will solve this. in webSockets we can send handShake params ( like query String params ) , so the server authenticate client based on handShake params or reject connection before accepting ! , can we do same in tcp sockets ?

Comment: The SO admins don't like extended discussions on answers; you should really ask a new question and reference this one. The easiest solution is to set the `soTimeout`, but that will apply to the entire conversation, not just the handshake; we don't currently provide a way to change the timeout after the handshake. You can start a timer when you get the `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` and cancel it when the handshake completes, or close the socket if the timer expires.